# Is there an algorithm to determine if some imperative code is referentially transparent?

Tags: compiler-construction, functional-programming, static-analysis

Is there an algorithm which can determine, given a chunk `X` of imperative code (and the surrounding program), if that code is referentially transparent?

What I have so far is:

> A piece of code is RT if
>
> 1. No non-reference variables which are assigned to in X are read after control flow leaves X
> 2. All reference variables which are de-referenced and assigned to in X can be proved to refer to variables following rule 1
> 3. No variables are read, or functions called, whose values depend on run-time state (ie `scanf()`, `time()`, `argv`)

EDIT: see comment

<strike>Perfect accuracy of this algorithm isn't an absolute necessity, but it is preferable. (This is real life, not a CS class, so [as that one guy says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse_is_better), "It is slightly better to be simple than correct.")</strike>

EDIT 2:

An algorithm sketch/idea for a simplified language with no references or pointers, represented as an Abstract Syntax Tree:

> 1. Find cause/effect pairs (ie assignment and use of a variable)
> 2. For each pair, mark parent nodes in the AST as non-RT up to and not including the lowest common ancestor.

Problems: What to do about initializers? Do they count as assignments?

Comment: NB In compiler construction, as opposed to other software development, I disagree with "simple is better than correct". Correctness is a deal breaker. You don't want to causes two-week debugging nightmares caused by code being analyzed (and then transformed) incorrectly, leading to heisenbugs. Of course, you can still go for simple by doing it not at all if the correct solution isn't simple, but the problem you choose is inherently non-simple.

Comment: Tagging as static analysis!  Where this belongs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to decide whether two pieces of code are referentially transparent in *general*?  No.  Why?  Because *no program analysis* can be perfectly accurate (proof: tons of different formulations, basically the halting problem).  However, you can be *approximate*.  In general, there are a few techniques to prove what types of programs are definitely referentially transparent (because we error on the conservative side of inapproximation, there will necessarily be some programs which are correct but cannot be shown to be correct):

- First, you need to fix a language.  The analysis depends on the language, and the complexity of the analysis will change a lot depending on what baked in things your language has: concurrency, references, pointers, all hard to deal with.  (References and pointers are not the same, in general dealing with arbitrary pointer arithmetic will be harder than simple references!)
- You can look at some theorem provers or model checkers.  These tools can be used to check if two programs have the same output, by deriving formulas that model the program and then attempt to decide if they describe the same sets of behavior.
- [Separation logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_logic) is a very popular and growing technique to prove two imperative programs correct, in the presence of pointers.  The basic idea is to reason compositionally about *disjoint* parts of the heap (why is this good?  Consider you write a linked list implementation, now you combine it with some code that randomly writes into the middle of that linked list.  That's hell for verification.)
- In the functional world, people try to apply equational reasoning to their code.  While this isn't entirely the same in imperative programs, you can do something similar if you use [monads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29) to model heap assertions.

Are there tools out there that you can apply off the shelf to large code bases?  No, because large code bases use things that are not amenable to reasoning about (reflection, difficult classes of aliasing, etc..).  Essentially your problem reduces to some sort of theorem proving, where you need to be able to *prove* two programs are equivalent.  There are tons of papers that tackle this for subproblems.  For example, consider very simple programs written in a toy language ([Imp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMP_programming_language) is a popular example!), tons of papers try to tackle things like this.

Comment: Yeah, as far as I'm aware you can probably design a new imperative language specifically to support this kind of analysis. But realistically existing programs in existing languages will almost always do something that leads to a "not guaranteed to be referentially transparent" result.

Comment: I wouldn't say necessarily so.  For example, there has definitely been some work on doing things like symbolic execution, or model checking, to prove a referentially transparent "optimized" implementation of a function results.  However, when you work with large things that touch the heap, then yes.  As always, dealing with pointers (or higher order functions, etc..) ends up being hard.

Comment: @Ben by the way, this is why people use more purely functional languages, right :-), because reasoning about referential transparency  (and many other properties) is much more easily compositional when you don't have to worry about the pesky heap!

Comment: @KristopherMicinski Not just the pesky heap, pesky assignments too.

Comment: @Dan perhaps I should have said "store"

Comment: @Dan though I would also argue that a lot of static analysis do relatively well when you have "local" assignments, to things not really on the heap, so that pointers really end up really being the problem.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski Good, because the language I'm designing doesn't make pointers directly available to the user, just references and nullable references.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read about "effect systems" or "type and effect systems", which are a mechanism for describing and tracking what kinds of side effects a computation has. I'm not sure if there are any systems capable of doing inference rather than relying on effect annotations, but at least you should be able to get a sense of what you have to worry about.